# macOS Notarization and multiple embedded tools/bundles

Tags: macos, notarize

My product is a System Pref Pane which contains multiple embedded apps to do its job, including:

- A background-only renderer.
- An app to handle a Menu Status Item.
- An app to check for updates since System Preferences might not be running.
- An installer that simply copies the System Pref Pane into place (needed because of a code-signing bug that prevents direct distribution of the prefPane).
- A unix executable relaunch tool to handle loading into System Preferences during an update. This one seems impossible to staple a notarization to.

I have a nice script in Xcode that packages all this together. With Notarization, will I now need to notarize each of these individually starting at the deepest point? That sounds like a total hassle since automating it is difficult with the delay/polling required at Apple.

Will just Notarizing the outter-most container be enough?

I'm looking for suggestions from others that have multiple executables in a single app package as to dealing with Notarization.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a vendor customer service question and not a programming question.

Comment: I think it is a programming question - esp since there seems to be no way to notarize a unix executable. How can I use altool to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Each nested helper app may be codesigned first, and the outer app is deep codesigned using `--preserve-metadata`. Then the outer app may be notarized.  The unix executable can be codesigned if you make a mini bundle folder containing the executable, an Info.plist, and possibly Entitlements.plist. You can notarize a `ditto` .zip of the bundle, and `stapler staple` the mini bundle. But I find with inherited security, just the outer app needs the notary as long as the inner apps have their individual sub-app codesigning metadata preserved.

Comment: The outer-most app is an installer so it will only be run once to copy the embedded .prefPane into System Preferences (~/Library/PreferencePanes). Right now everything is signed from the inside out, but I am wondering if I need to Notarize the .prefPane separately from Notarizing the Installer. On my 10.15 test machine, lack of Notarization (even on the installer) does not seem to prevent things from running.

Answer (score 2):

You can notarize top level package(zip, dmg , pkg)
From [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow#3087720):

> The notary service accepts disk images (UDIF format), signed flat
>   installer packages, and ZIP archives. **It processes nested containers
>   as well**, like packages inside a disk image.